# Libre Office - Single Column Pie Chart

Tags: charts, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, cells, statistics

I want to create a pie chart, for a single column that looks like this:

[image]

I tried to select the range, click on Insert -> Chart -> Pie-Chart, but regardless of what I try, I always get an empty chart?
Not quiet sure what I am doing wrong.

Can someone guide me the steps to create a pie chart, that shows how many % are Open-Source, how many % are proprietary and how many are ??? (Unknown). Empty cells should be ignored.

Also - is it possible to process the entry that has both `Open-Source, Proprietary` as one for each? Basically treat is as two entries, if that makes sense.
I know there are already plenty of posts for similar things, but most of them address either multi-column data, and the other ones didn't help me much.
I am just not seeing a chart at all, it just stays empty :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a pivot table, then using the data from the pivot table to create a chart. Here are the steps:

1. Select you data. Then on the menu, select Insert -> Pivot table. On the Select Source window, choose Current selection, then OK.

[image: IMG:]

2. On the Pivot Table Layout window, drag and drop Source from Available field to Row fields and Data fields. Double-click on "Sum - Source" on the Data fields, select Count.
   Click on Displayed value, on Type, select `% of total`.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

3. Click OK. The window will look like the image below, Click OK.

[image: IMG:]

4. The pivot table will be create with the percentage of each distinct value on a new column.

[image: IMG:]

5. Select the pivot table (or a cell inside the pivot table), then on the menu bar Insert -> Chart. Select Pie chart, then OK.
6. Right click on the Chart, select Edit. Right-click on the chart again, select Insert data labels. Labels will be shown on the chart.

[image: IMG:]

7. Right-click on the chart one more time, select Format data labels. Then select Show value as percentage. Click OK.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

8. Your chart will be display the percentage of your categories as seen on the image below

[image: IMG:]

**EDIT:**  To split the value "Open-Source, Proprietary" into 2 distinct categories, select the cell you want to split (if the row on its right has value, it is better to insert an empty column before continuing). On the menu bar, click Data -> Text to Columns. On the window that opens, select Comma, Space and Merge delimiters. Click OK

[image: IMG:]

The cell will be split as shown on the image below

[image: IMG:]

Copy both cells, then select the original cell (the cell that contained the data) then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. For the options, select Transpose; on Shift Cells, select Down. Click OK.

[image: IMG:]

The values will be insert as shown on the image below. You can then delete the column inserted a few steps back.

[image: IMG:]

It is preferable to do the splitting before creating the pivot table. If done after, go back to the pivot table and refresh it. The chart will also be refreshed with the new values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is already really helpful, - but the splitting/processing of the combined string ("Open-Source, Proprietary") is important. I need a way to tear them apart and add one to each category.

Comment: @Kyu96 See edit part

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use numericals for pie charts if it doesnt let you do what you are trying to do,  natively. I tried it out and got this, so I think you should manually calculate the number or percentage and then make another entry for it.

[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo1qO.png) i just did, you need numericals. Perhaps you can use a count formula or something to generate the number and from there, pipe this information into a pie chart. I don't have the knowledge to know how to do that but I imagine its not too difficult - Google is your friend :)